# M2: Cannot gather stats warning

Tags: magento2, catalog

One of the products in my store don't have image associated with it, infact image was available on staging server and when moved to production image is no more available. I'm trying to re-upload the image but soon as I hit edit product button it issues following error (warning):

> Cannot gather stats! Warning!stat(): stat failed for /var/www/vhosts/example.co.uk/example.co.uk/pub/media/catalog/product/b/u/business.jpg

Comment: Looks like permission issue. Please check with your hosting provider

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a bug in Magento2 which can be reproduced by following these step:

1. Upload an image to product
2. Delete product image from files (pub/media)
3. Edit the product in admin panel and you'll see this error

**Fix**

Fix is provided by Magento team on [Github](https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/2db5aa15722307fb6ad703627933224f5f74bbe3)

Answer (score 3):

Please run below sql code

```
SET @file = '/b/u/business.jpg';
START TRANSACTION;
DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_media_gallery WHERE value = @file;
DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar WHERE value = @file;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Hii https://prnt.sc/vna70x I was facing the same issue in my project so I have found that the 3.png file was missing in the pub/media/amasty/flags/ directory and after adding this file my issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

in my case it was permission issue:

```
sudo chmod -R 0777 var/ pub/ generated/
sudo rm -rf var/cache/* var/view_preprocessed/* generated/* pub/static/*
sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

and it worked.