# Products in Backend not loading in Magento 2 after Data Migrate from Magento 1.9.4.3

Tags: magento2, magento2-migration-tool

I migrate first settings then data with magento data migration tool. Everything looks good, but in Backend I try to edit some product but unsuccessful. Ajax loader stay and not closing.
I try to make reindex, deploy and compile but issue is not resolved.
In console I get this error. Please for help. Thanks

[image]

Comment: please you check log error

Comment: This is write in exception log
Cannot gather stats! Warning!stat(): stat failed for /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento2/pub/media/catalog/product/2/0/20-lb-qb-weight-pockets_ac3220_buckle-view.png {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\FileSystemException(code: 0): Cannot gather stats! Warning!stat(): stat failed for /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento2/pub/media/catalog/product/2/0/20-lb-qb-weight-pockets_ac3220_buckle-view.png at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php:73)"} []

Comment: Please refer this links :- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/139318/m2-cannot-gather-stats-warning any query let me know

Comment: This error in log is because missing media for all products. I added pictures for this product  and after that I don't have  error in log anymore. I think the problem is because any of attributes is recurring, but I don't know which attribute.

Comment: you apply the permission ??

Comment: Yes permissions I setup for Magento 2 , on files 644, folders 755 and pub/media is 777. I don't know what is the problem, now log is empty... A strange issue :(

Comment: you run the setup and deploy command ??

Comment: Yes, I run all , deploy -f , setup upgrade , flush cache, also  reindex but nothing is change :(

Answer (score 0):

Please try to run this command:

```
update eav_attribute set attribute_code = attribute_id where attribute_code is null or attribute_code = ''
```