# Uploaded images on product via admin shows 0 byes

Tags: magento2.3

Magento 2.3.5 - p2

When we upload images from the Admin to Products, we see it uploaded but after saving it. We saw that images show the default Magento product image and the size of the image becomes 0 bytes.

Logs

We see this on the log

```
[2021-03-18 12:20:03] main.WARNING: Cannot gather stats! Warning!stat(): stat failed for /home/elsdfsdf/public_html/pub/media/catalog/product/r/u/rubens_tummies_handmade_swedish_organic_wheat_dolls_rubens_barn_children_cosying_with_group_5.jpg {"exception":"[object] (Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException(code: 0): Cannot gather stats! Warning!stat(): stat failed for /home/elsdfsdf/public_html/pub/media/catalog/product/r/u/rubens_tummies_handmade_swedish_organic_wheat_dolls_rubens_barn_children_cosying_with_group_5.jpg at /home/elsdfsdf/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php:72)"} []
```

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/139318/m2-cannot-gather-stats-warning

Comment: This not working on magento 2.3.5 - p2 it results to gallery bucket errors etc